# Convert all Date properties (including nested) to string in a TypeScript generic type

Tags: typescript, amazon-dynamodb

AWS DynamoDB doesn't store `Date` values, so all date/time values need to be serialized into ISO 8601 strings before storing, and then need to be deserialized from strings to `Date` when retrieving.

I've created a pair of generic TypeScript helper functions to do this serialization and deserialization. But I'm not sure how to make these functions type-safe.  I also don't want to deal with maintaining pairs of normal vs. serialized types-- instead I just want to define the "normal" type and use a generic type definition to define the serialized type.

Specifically, given some type `T` which may have `Date`-typed properties (either at top level or in nested objects) I want to create a type definition for `Serialized<T>` that has the same shape as `T` except that all `Date`-typed properties are replaced with `string`. Is this possible?

For example, given an object that looks like this:

```
interface OriginalType {
  foo: Date, 
  bar: number, 
  nested: { 
    created: Date 
  } 
}
```

I want to end up with a type like the one below: (but without manually typing in the definition)

```
interface SerializedType {
  foo: string, 
  bar: number, 
  nested: { 
    created: string
  } 
}
```

What should be the declaration for `Serialized<T>`?

Comment: I'm curious how your deserialization routine knows which string fields need to be converted to dates.  If your system processes untrusted data, I hope you didn't just assume that any string that looks like a date should be converted to a date.

Comment: @MattMcCutchen - It's not a great solution, but I'm using a naming convention on object key names to identify date-based fields-- specifically to avoid the problem of untrusted data. Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: Good!  I think a naming convention is about the best you can do without an explicit "schema" object of some kind that tells you which fields to convert.  If you did have a schema, you could generate the TypeScript types from it.

Comment: @MattMcCutchen - Yep, agreed. Another nice solution could be automatically applying that naming convention only in the stored types, e.g. `{a: Date, b: number}` serializes to `{date_a: string, b: number}` and vice versa. The JS part of that conversion is easy but I don't think that TS can perform string operations (e.g. add/remove prefix) on property names in mapped types. Right?

Comment: Right, there is no string manipulation in the TypeScript type system.  You could do something like `{a: {_date: string}, b: number}` (reminiscent of the format used by [Meteor's EJSON](https://docs.meteor.com/api/ejson.html) and maybe other libraries) if you don't mind the extra nesting.

Comment: Yeah I considered that option but DynamoDB has limitations on querying nested objects so can't do that. :-(

Comment: Why not use a library like [dynamo-easy](https://github.com/shiftcode/dynamo-easy) which takes care of the [date mapping](https://shiftcode.gitbook.io/dynamo-easy/api/model/decorators#dateproperty-options) for you. _full disclosure: I am one of the authors of the library_

Comment: Hi @wittwermic - Good idea, but too late. I've already moved to MongoDB for, among many reasons: collation (case-insensitive) indexes, array indexes, indexing of nested fields, opinionated ObjectID type, etc.  If I work on DynamoDB in the future I'll definitely check out your library.  Thanks!  BTW, MongoDB's `js-bson` library solved the date-serialization issues above so I was able to rip out a bunch of serialization code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are looking for a recursive homomorphic [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types) (to iterate over the fields) using a [conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#conditional-types) (to check whether each field is a date).

```
type Serialized<T> = {
    [P in keyof T]: T[P] extends Date ? string : Serialized<T[P]>
};
```

This solution takes advantage of the special rule that applying a homomorphic mapped type such as `Serialized` to a primitive type returns the primitive type, regardless of the body of the homomorphic mapped type.

Comment: This is a reaaaaaly nice typescript feature that I didn't know. Thank you so much for that. You elevated my types to a new level